# PictureBbox for Game Character

Tags: background, components, transparency, picturebox

I'm just a beginner in programming. Right now I am familiarizing myself to it and I am using Vb.net as a practice.

I am trying to make a basic game in VS2019 and I use picturebox as a component for the character to move. Whenever I am moving it, there is a line appearing on the opposite side of the direction which where the character is going.

I figured out that this is because of the property of the picturebox, the picturebox itself is moving on a form with a background picture so whenever it is moving, the color of the form is what is appearing as the color of the line(borders of the picturebox).

Is there anyone that can teach me how can I be able to fix it? Thank you.

I try to search for solutions but I cannot be able to fully understand their solution or if their situation is same as mine. I found something here on stackoverflow about making a custom component. But whenever I am trying to make my own custom component base on what is in their guide, I cannot be able to proceed because of I cannot be able to understand it. In their guide, it says that I must create a custom component and make it inherit the original picturebox, but when I try to copy the exact thing I see, it shows an error like this.

"Base class 'PictureBox specified for class 'TransparentPictureBox cannot be different from the base class Component of one of its other partial types."